# Getting JSON string into object and then get key

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a api call which returns this as a json string:

```
{
   "packetId":0,
   "responses":[
      {
         "data":{
            "abTestingId":44,
            "lastLogin":1661337984021,
            "server_time":1661337984051,
            "refundCount":0,
            "timeZoneOffset":1.0,
            "experiencePoints":0,
            "maxBundleMsgs":10,
            "createdAt":1660804158513,
            "parentProfileId":null,
            "emailAddress":null,
            "experienceLevel":0,
            "countryCode":null,
            "vcClaimed":0,
            "currency":{
               
            },
            "id":"8dd0a185-0ac5-42fa-9669-d55f7c6ad6a8",
            "compressIfLarger":51200,
            "amountSpent":0,
            "previousLogin":1661337931133,
            "playerName":"test1",
            "pictureUrl":null,
            "incoming_events":[
               
            ],
            "sessionId":"cohhbvvcm7admtipiu1pcdgbek",
            "languageCode":"en",
            "vcPurchased":0,
            "isTester":false,
            "summaryFriendData":null,
            "loginCount":37,
            "emailVerified":true,
            "xpCapped":false,
            "profileId":"8dd0a185-0ac5-42fa-9669-d55f7c6ad6a8",
            "newUser":"false",
            "playerSessionExpiry":1200,
            "sent_events":[
               
            ],
            "maxKillCount":11,
            "rewards":{
               "rewardDetails":{
                  
               },
               "currency":{
                  
               },
               "rewards":{
                  
               }
            },
            "statistics":{
               
            }
         },
         "status":200
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, I am then converting this to an object like this:

```
object returnData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
```

Now, my question is... How do I access the "rewards" object?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: declare as `var` instead of object for your deserialized resultant. did you try `returnData.responses[0].data.rewards` ?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran - I am not allowed to do this: returnData.responses[0]. Redline under responses

Comment: @mansa if you do not have model classes, then your compiler will not recognize and show those red lines. If the api response is not static, then you need to read and access the properties dynamically. REFER https://code-maze.com/csharp-deserialize-json-into-dynamic-object/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var rewardsValue = returnData.GetValue("rewards");
```

This will give the value of the key(reward).

Answer (score 0):

```
JObject o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonresponse);
var responses = o.GetValue("responses").ToObject<List<JObject>>();
foreach (var r in responses){
    Console.WriteLine(r.GetValue("data").ToObject<JObject>().GetValue("rewards"));
}
```

This is one way, if you don't want to deserialise the api response directly to a POCO object (not much effort needed thanks to tools like https://json2csharp.com/ that create the C# class for you based on the JSON object).

Answer (score 0):

if you need just rewards you can get it after  json parsing

```
var rewards = JObject.Parse(json)["responses"]
                         .Select(d => (JObject)d["data"]["rewards"]).ToList();

var rewardDetails = rewards[0]["rewardDetails"];
```

if you need more properties, maybe it would be better to deserialize json to c# clases.